# Unable to trigger API endpoint execution under '/find/{id}'

Tags: go, mux

I've started a small personal API as a learning exercise with Go and while trying to test it I found that the endpoint GET `/find/{id}` isn't triggered when doing such call in Postman.

Mux Router:

```
router.HandleFunc("/find/{id}", controller.Find).Methods("GET")
```

Controller method:

```
func Find(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    id := vars["id"]

    ...
}
```

And the former call to the API:

```
localhost:8080/find/[cb&%AD%87"%8CV
```

Maybe it's something really simple that I can't really see?

Comment: What makes you say it isn't triggered?

Comment: @Adrian break points, but the thing is that with a simple input such as 'abc' it triggers. The thing is that the given input, a complex ID, isn't triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Gorilla mux,

The implementation is similar, and you can read more about it [in here](https://github.com/gorilla/mux)

```
    package HTTPServer

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type Routes []Route

var routes = Routes{
    {"GetFirstForm", "GET", "/firstForm/{id}", GetFirstForm}{


//GetFirstForm getting first form by ECO id
func GetFirstForm(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
var vars = mux.Vars(r)


ecoID := vars["id"]     
///your logic
    }
```

Comment: How does this differ from/fix OP's issue?